# Could someone explain the life of a sessionStorage object?

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at a few websites and each of them are slightly different. I understand the basic functionality, but its life time is not so obvious. On Google (Developers) it said it only exists for a specific tab in that instance, but others said you could access it from the same tab or other tabs as long as its the same domain name. Could someone please clear that up for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Session Storage is a global object that maintains a storage area that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: One minor situation to be aware of: The Chrome "Duplicate Tab" option will still open a page with its own private sessionStorage, but its initial data contents are copied from the source page. So, a duplicated page gets duplicated (but not shared) sessionStorage.